# i want to retrieve json data via url with android

Tags: android, json, http, url

i'm working on a API, and i want to take the json data that is display in an adress like this : https://api.empireavenue.com/profile/info/?apikey=YOURAPIKEY&username=TICKER&password=PASSWORD

and take this data to display it on my app .
Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the data or how to get the json data to your application?

Comment: i know how to parse, but the data i want to parse is created on a webpage, and the only wait to get this data is via url.

Answer (score 0):

The input to the parseJson method should be whatever you get back from the HTTP request.  This also assumes the format is something like:

{"rootKey":{"intVal":1}}

You will have to modify the order in which you query objects depending on the structure.

```
private static final ROOT_JSON_KEY = "rootKey";
private static final INT_VALUE_NAME = "intVal"; 

public void parseJson(String webServiceResponse) {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(webServiceResponse);
    JSONObject rootObject = json.getJSONObject(ROOT_KEY);
    int intValues = rootObject.getInt(INT_VALUE_NAME);

}
```

EDIT: Sorry, stupid coding error.

Comment: But what is the webserviceresponse ? Is it a inputstream or a httpentity or ?

Comment: and do you know how to do it with a JsonArray ?